# Array issues within function in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, function

I want to create a function that starts off with the first two elements in an array, and then creates the Fibonacci sequence from them, but it creates a weird matrix with decimals and such, and it's twice the number of columns I want every time. When I looked it up, this is what I came up with after struggling through the documentation.

I have almost no experience with MATLAB, and I'm used to python. I haven't been able to find anything that really addresses my problem. Or helps.

```
function [f,s] = fibb(nmax)
f = array(1,0);
% first two items in array are 0 and 1 respectively
for n = 3 : 1 : nmax
    f(n) = [f(n-1) + f(n-2) newElem];
    % Adds new entry, entry is sum of previous two
end
s = sum(f);
% sum of the sequence
```

Comment: What is `array(1,0)`?

Answer (score 0):

`array` is not an in-built function in Matlab. Also, a Fibonacci sequence starts with `[1,1]`.

Try the following:

```
function [f,s] = fibb(nmax)
    f = [1,1];
    for n = 3 : nmax
        f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2);
    end
    s = sum(f);
end
```

There is probably a more efficient approach, but this should be a working version of your code.

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to what RPM wrote, I would suggest that you preallocate your f vector to make it work a bit faster. Just substitute the `f = [1,1]` command with the one below:

```
f = ones(1,nmax);
```

Otherwise matlab has to dynamically increase the size of your vector in each loop, making your function slower.